# how o skip characters in the sax parser perl

Tags: xml, perl, special-characters, saxparser

I have a problem in reading special characters in perl. I have the following xml file and Iam using a sax parser which loop on each hotel and take the values but when it read HotelInfo it we skip the text because we have a special charterers in the 1000 mï¿½

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLResponse>
    <ResponseType>HotelListResponse</ResponseType>
    <RequestInfo>
        <AffiliateCode>NI9373</AffiliateCode>
        <AffRequestId>2</AffRequestId>
        <AffRequestTime>2015-10-29T15:52:05</AffRequestTime>
    </RequestInfo>
    <TotalNumber>264234</TotalNumber>
    <Hotels>
        <Hotel>
            <HotelCode>AD0BFU</HotelCode>
            <OldHotelId>0</OldHotelId>
            <HotelLocation/>
            <HotelInfo>Renovated in 2001, Hotel Bringue features a 1000 mï¿½ garden and comprises 5 floors with 105 double rooms, 2 suites and 7 single rooms. Hotel Bringue is situated in the picturesque village El Serrat, boasting the most amazing mountain views in the region and just a short drive to the main ski resort of Vallnord.After an exhausting day, you can go for a relaxing swim in the pool, re-energise your body in the jacuzzi or pamper yourself in the sauna. The rooms are beautifully appointed and come with an array of modern amenities for a pleasant stay.</HotelInfo>
            <HotelTheme>Ski Hotels</HotelTheme>
        </Hotel>
    </Hotels>
</XMLResponse>
```

How I can skip like there characters in the sax parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to fix the file, I'm not sure why an XML parser is even needed here.

```
perl -i~ -pe's/\xC3\xAF\xC2\xBF\xC2\xBD//g' file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you define  "special characters"? One definition might be: non-ASCII characters. ASCII characters are in the range 0x00 - 0x7f (although not all are valid in XML).  So you could discard every character that is **not** in that range with something like:

```
$data =~ s/[^\x00-\x7f]//g;
```

But that is potentially going to throw away a lot of perfectly good data.  All accented characters will be discarded (eg: the "ü" in "Zürich" - leaving "Zrich").  Currency symbols like €, £ or ¥ (or even ¢) will be lost.  You'll also lose otherwise harmless characters like –,—, “, ”, or • and invisible characters like non-breaking spaces.

So the question is why do you want to discard these characters?  At what point are they becoming a problem?  I notice you've tagged the question 'mysql' - do you get a problem when you try to insert the data in a database?  Have you declared the encoding of the database correctly?  Have you enabled [mysql_enable_utf8](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#mysql_enable_utf8) on your database connection?  Maybe you could do your insert in an `eval` block and only apply the regex above if the insert fails.

Another option may be to pass the data through [Encoding::FixLatin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encoding::FixLatin).  Which should make the string safe to insert into a UTF-8 database, even if the resulting characters aren't exactly what was originally intended.

By the way, I think in the specific instance above, the data originally said:

```
Hotel Bringue features a 1000 m² garden
```

The [SUPERSCRIPT TWO](http://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/?c=U+00B2) character is Unicode U+00B2 and in UTF-8 that would be encoded as two bytes: C2 B2.  Somewhere along the line a process may have read those bytes but decoded them as Latin-1 rather than UTF-8 and each byte got turned into a character.  This double encoding can happen over and over when data has the wrong encoding declaration or people fail to understand how to work with Unicode characters - causing one character to turn into many characters of garbage.